# How to wrap height according to child content for showModalBottomSheet or remove auto height

Tags: flutter, modal-dialog, height

I have one bottom sheet and under that  bottom sheet i am managing routing
my each screen have different screen size. and i want to change the height of `showModalBottomSheet` for each screen.

```
showModalBottomSheet<void>(
      context: context,
      isDismissible: true,
      //isScrollControlled: true,
      elevation: 2.0,
      barrierColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0),
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        // double ht = Provider.of<SearchByLocationNotify>(context).getScreenSize;
        return SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,// currently static height provided
            child: PopUpHome());
      },
    );
```

1. change the height according to each screen
2. or wrap the content of children so that static height is not needed

[image]

In the above image red porion is `showModalBottomSheet`  blue is my child so i want red portion should only occupy blue.

Answer (score -1):

return a Column with mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min from the builder and place your content inside the Column widget.

Comment: return Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            PopUpHome(),
          ],
        );

Like this??

Comment: yes, try that it should work..

Comment: that approch not woring. I'm adjusting height using provider on each route.
but i dont want to go woth this approach